# Is it safe to change the id of an asp control, in an already published website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to change the id of an asp control from a server. This server has an already published version of the website, which consists of (among others) the `.aspx` files and the compiled `.cs` files (dll's).

From an `.aspx` file, I want to change this asp control:

```
<asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server" Width="450">
```

to this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="anotherPanelId" runat="server" Width="450">
```

and since the `.aspx` files (even when published) are in a format that can be changed, I would like to do it directly on the published version in the server and avoid re-compiling.

I can confirm that although the control has the attribute `"runat='server'"`, **it is not actually being used by it's corresponding .cs file.**

So... is it safe to change this id, or do I have to recompile the website?

Comment: If it's not being used by the code-behind, why do you need to change it?

Comment: well... i am creating other asp controls dynamically in the same page, and there is a possibility that the id 'panel1' will have the same id as a dynamically generated control

Comment: Then why not just make sure they don't have the same name? Anyway, just try it, see what happens, roll back if it fails. It will be fine unless you use the ID.

Comment: Due to the fact that the website is already pusblished and uploaded to the server, i wanted to avoid re-publishing it. Making changes in to the dynamically generated ids, means re-compilation. Just changing the asp control id from the 'aspx' (directly from the server) is a way to avoid re-compiling

Comment: Also, why do you care so much about avoiding publishing? Do it often and get used to it.

Comment: If your site is not precompiled you can replace both the .aspx and the .cs files. You may need to recycle the app pool, I don't recall for sure.

Comment: I'm with @DavidG here. Even if modifying the .aspx (and not the.cs or the compiled dlls) can work under some conditions, it can fail orribly under other (very common) conditions. Building a project is quick, deploying only an .aspx or the whole project/solution should be the same effort, more or less. So why not to go with the "right" way?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I am aware of the proper way of doing such changes. There are other project-specific complications in this case, which do not allow me to re-compile and upload so easily. I just wanted to know if someone who has deeper understanding of the asp architecture than me, can verify if this is safe or not.